# Cannot access Hubconnection() from vs 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms, signalr

I'm working on cross domain implementation of `SignalR` in asp .net web application using VS 2010 .

My problems it that I'am unable to access `HubConnection()` from my application . I have installed  SignalR version 0.5.3 . I have searched for namespace of  `HubConnection()` but couldn't find any. Can anyone tell me the namespace of `HubConnection()` or the reason why I'm not able to access.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SignalR;

namespace SignalRVersion5
{
    public partial class TestServerEvent : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:58416/");
            var chat = connection.CreateProxy("chat");
            chat.On<string>("addMessage", Console.WriteLine);
            try
            {
                connection.Start().Wait();
                string msg = null;
                while ((msg = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    chat.Invoke("send", msg).Wait();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (var error = ex.GetError()) // NEW ERROR HANDLING FEATURES
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use older version of signalr? BTW, I dont know about the problem (I am new)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the SignalR Client package available on NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

You should be using the 1.0.0 RC2 version of SignalR. 0.5.3 is out of date.

Once you install the correct client package, you should us the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs` namespace.

The documentation at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki is continuously kept up to date with the latest versions of SignalR. The following documentation pertains to using the .NET client library with hubs: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, using SignalR.Client 0.5.1.1.  If you are creating a new project I would definitely recommend having a look at SignalR 1.0 first.

```
using SignalR.Client.Hubs;

var hubConnection = new HubConnection(HUB_URL);
var hub = hubConnection.CreateProxy(HUB_NAME);

Console.WriteLine("Starting connection");

await hubConnection.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Connected");

var start = DateTime.Now;
var question = new Question
{
    Text = "text message",
    Time = start.ToString("d")
}
};

await hub.Invoke("Ask", question);
hubConnection.Stop();
```